# Pull app's files on after-L devices

Tags: android, adb

I used to be able to pull file from my app's files directory this way:

```
adb shell "run-as $PACKAGE chmod 777 /data/data/$PACKAGE/files/"
adb shell "run-as $PACKAGE chmod 666 /data/data/$PACKAGE/files/$FILENAME"
adb pull /data/data/$PACKAGE/files/$FILENAME .
adb shell "run-as $PACKAGE chmod 700 /data/data/$PACKAGE/files/"
adb shell "run-as $PACKAGE chmod 600 /data/data/$PACKAGE/files/$FILENAME"
```

It worked well on pre-L devices. When I try to get files the same way at L and further, I get "permission denied" error.

I found workaround, but question is: what change in Android L causes this error?